# Reverse multiple CSS transformations in a descendant

Tags: css, transform

I have used the `skewX` and `skewY` to tranform a box in css. However, I want to put text on that plane but can't reverse the effect:

```css
.a3 {
  transform: skewX(69deg) skewY(-10.6deg);
}
.a3 > p {
  transform: skewX(-69deg) skewY(10.6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="a3">
  <p>Foo bar</p>
</div>
```

With the code above, the text is still skewed.

The method of reversing the skew only worked when there was 1 skew, but not when it's both x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformations aren't commutative in general.

Let `S = S₁ S₂` the matrix of the transformations on the outer element, where `S₁` and `S₂` are the matrices of `skewX(69deg)` and `skewY(-10.6deg)`, respectively.

You want to undo the transforms on the inner element. That is, you want to apply a `T` transformation to the inner element, so that `S T = I`, where `I` is the identity matrix.

Linear algebra tells us that

```
S T = I   ==>   T = S⁻¹ = (S₁ S₂)⁻¹ = S₂⁻¹ S₁⁻¹
```

Effectively, now the final transformation for the inner element is

```
S T = (S₁ S₂) (S₂⁻¹ S₁⁻¹) = S₁ (S₂ S₂⁻¹) S₁⁻¹ = S₁ I S₁⁻¹ = S₁ S₁⁻¹ = I
```

Getting back to your case, since the outer element has `skewX(69deg) skewY(-10.6deg)`, first you must undo `skewY(-10.6deg)`, and then undo `skewX(69deg)`.

Therefore, the inner element needs

```css
transform: skewY(10.6deg) skewX(-69deg);
```

```css
.a3 {
  transform: skewX(69deg) skewY(-10.6deg);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.a3 p {
  transform: skewY(10.6deg) skewX(-69deg);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a3">
  <p>Foo bar</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect - I didn't know the order made a difference!